# WCF only one way calls are working

Tags: c#, wcf

For some reason when I call service method that `IsOneWay=true` everything works fine, callback is returned as expected every time. But when I use method that `IsOneWay=false`, no errors are shown on client side but that method on server side is not called. What could be cause of this? Only thing that I did was small refactoring in logic that handles service instance in client side.

**Client side logic**

```
public interface ISomeServiceClient
{
    IService Instance { get; }
}

public class SomeServiceClient : ISomeServiceClient
{
    private ServiceClient client;
    private IServiceCallback callback;
    private System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext;

    public SomeServiceClient()
    {
        this.callback = new ServiceCallback();
        this.instanceContext = new System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext(callback);
        this.client = new ServiceClient(instanceContext);
    }

    public IService Instance
    {
        get { return this.client; }
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    private readonly IService serviceClient;
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        this.serviceClient = SharedService.Instance.ServiceClient   
    }   
    public void RetrieveData()
    {
      // Then I just call server side like this
        this.serviceClient.GetSomeData();
    }
}
```

Note: `SharedService` is sigleton that returns `IService` new instance of `SomeServiceClient` if not yet initialized.

**Server side data contracts**

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public partial class Service : IService
{
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallback))]
public interface IService : ISomeDataService
{   
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISomeDataServiceCallback))]
public interface ISomeDataService
{
     [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
     List<Data> GetSomeData();
}
```

I don't know if it's necessary to show also service configuration but here it goes..

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.Library.Models.Service">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
          <!-- ip changed for demo purposes -->
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://111.111.11.111:2222/MyService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://111.111.11.111:2222/MyService" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="TcpConfig" 
                  contract="MyService.Library.Interfaces.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TcpConfig">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have also tried to use other methods that are not one way call, and they are also not calling service.
As I mentioned, no code was changed in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Callback methods in your service, you are using Duplex contract as the messaging pattern between client and server.

**A duplex contract consists of *two one-way contracts between the client and the server* and does not require that the method calls be correlated. We generally, use this kind of contract when your service must query the client for more information or explicitly raise events on the client**